# Trying to Remove for-Loops from Python code, Performing Operations with a Look-up Table On Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, vectorization

I feel like this is a similar problem to the one I asked before, but I can't figure it out. How can I convert these two lines of code into one line with no for-loop?

```
for i in xrange(X.shape[0]):
  dW[:,y[i]] -= X[i]
```

In English, every row in matrix X should be subtracted from a corresponding column in matrix dW given by the vector y.

I should mention dW is DXC and X is NXD, so the transpose of X does not have the same shape as W, otherwise I could re-order the the rows of X, and take the transpose directly. However, it is possible for the columns in dW to have multiple corresponding rows which need to be subtracted.

I feel like I do not have a firm grasp of how indexing in python is supposed to work, which makes it difficult to remove unnecessary for-loops, or even to know what for-loops are possible to remove.

Comment: Indexing in Python is one thing; indexing in NumPy is another. The Python+NumPy combo is a powerful tool, but it is almost like a whole new language.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1** Here's a one-liner vectorized approach with `matrix-multiplication` using [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) and [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
dWout -= (np.arange(dW.shape[1])[:,None] == y).dot(X).T
```

**Explanation :** Take a small example to understand what's going on -

Inputs :

```
In [259]: X
Out[259]: 
array([[ 0.80195208,  0.40566743,  0.62585574,  0.53571781],
       [ 0.56643339,  0.4635662 ,  0.4290103 ,  0.14457036],
       [ 0.31823491,  0.12329964,  0.41682841,  0.09544716]])

In [260]: y
Out[260]: array([1, 2, 2])
```

First off, we create the 2D mask of `y` indices spread across the length of dW's second axis.

Let `dW` be a `4 x 5` shaped array. So, the mask would be :

```
In [261]: mask = (np.arange(dW.shape[1])[:,None] == y)

In [262]: mask
Out[262]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

This is using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here to create a `2D` mask.

Next up, we use matrix-multiplication to sum-aggregate the same indices from `y` -

```
In [264]: mask.dot(X)
Out[264]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.80195208,  0.40566743,  0.62585574,  0.53571781],
       [ 0.8846683 ,  0.58686584,  0.84583872,  0.24001752],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Thus, corresponding to the third row of the mask that has `True` values at second and third columns, we would sum up the second and third rows from `X` with that matrix-multiplication. This would be put as the third row in the multiplication output.

Since, in the original loopy code we are updating `dW` across columns, we need to transpose the multiplication result and then update.

---

**Approach #2** Here's another vectorized way, though not a one-liner using [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) -

```
sidx = y.argsort()
unq,shift_idx = np.unique(y[sidx],return_index=True)
dWout[:,unq] -= np.add.reduceat(X[sidx],shift_idx,axis=0).T
```

Comment: can you explain how Approach #1 works? In particular, I don't understand why the "== y" part returns a matrix.

Comment: @resistancefm Added some explanation. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way to vectorize would be:

```
dW[:,y] -= X.T
```

Except, though not very obvious or well-documented, this will give problems with repeated indices in `y`. For these situations there is the `ufunc.at` method (elementwise operations in numpy are implemented as "ufunc's" or "universal functions"). Quote from [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

> ufunc.at(a, indices, b=None)
>
> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand ‘a’ for elements specified by ‘indices’. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to a[indices] += b, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once. For example, a[[0,0]] += 1 will only increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas add.at(a, [0,0], 1) will increment the first element twice.

So in your case:

```
np.subtract.at(dW.T, y, X)
```

Unfortunately, `ufunc.at` is relatively inefficient as far as vectorization techniques go, so the speedup compared to the loop might not be that impressive.

Comment: Ah lovely. I was trying out `np.ufunc.at` too, but was missing that transpose. Nice!